# One-at-a-time-Value Anomaly Detection Model with LSTM Autoencoder : Is it possible?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I'm currently working on a project about **anomaly detection** in dataflow, such as bank transaction file (so **time series datasets**). The datas I'm working on take the form of quite **small datasets**, with one additionnal **value arriving each month**, corresponding to one client bank account info (in the case of bank transaction file, account amount). I'm currently testing an AutoEncoder model to detect manually added anomalies in those datasets, but :

**I would like to know if it is possible to train my model, an AutoEncoder model, on previous values received, like a dataset of 50 to 100 element in size; and then test the next value received on this model, to check its relevance towards the whole dataset.**

Anomaly detection with AutoEncoder is based, in this/my case, on the **calculation of a threshold** to separate normal values to anomaly values : I based my threshold calculation on the **MAE Loss values between predicted and ground truth values**. But it implies quite an amount of datas in the tested part to generate enough relevant loss values to compare to the threshold, and that's my problem because with **only one value, my loss value is absurd** and not relevant at all towards the training set loss values and threshold.

I hope I have been clear enough in the description of my problem, and thank you in advance for your help !

**Here is my work path below **

- Datas I fed to my model to train on:

> First, because it's a time series dataset, I create sequence of X data from the dataset, and I assign to it the X+1 data :

```
def create_sequences(X, y, time_steps=TIME_STEPS):
    X_out, y_out = [], []
    for i in range(len(X)-time_steps):
        X_out.append(X.iloc[i:(i+time_steps)].values)
        y_out.append(y.iloc[i+time_steps])
    
    return np.array(X_out), np.array(y_out)

X_train, y_train = create_sequences(train[[column_[1]]], train[column_[1]])
```

- Then I fit the model with X and y values and make a prediction on training data :

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, mode='min')], shuffle=False)
```

- I compare prediction on training data to ground truth training data :

```
X_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)
train_mae_loss = np.mean(np.abs(X_train_pred - X_train), axis=1)
```

- I establish a threshold :

```
threshold = np.mean(train_mae_loss) + 2*np.std(train_mae_loss)
```

- I do the same with testing data, and compare the loss values from it to the threshold value from the training datas :

```
anomaly_df['anomaly'] = anomaly_df['loss'] > anomaly_df['threshold']
```

Comment: train_mae_loss = np.mean(np.abs(X_train_pred - X_train), axis=1) - did you mean y_train here?

Comment: You are not supposed to adjust the threshold during test/prediction - just keep the value learned on the train/validation set.

Comment: No, I mean X_train. I calculate this loss on the training truth and prediction for then calculating the threshold I will use on the losses calculated on the tested values. So I don't adjust the threshold during test/prediction, but only compare it to the loss values I got from the prediction on tested values, to set anomalous or non-anomalous values

Comment: Do you have an autoencoder, or a forecasting model? The model.fit(X_train, y_train) suggests that your model is forecasting - but your anomaly score calculation seems to be from a reconstructing autoencoder....